# How tell if an Int array is sorted in decreasing order or not? Do not use extra memory

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, swift2

```
var input = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

How do I check if the input array is in decreasing order?

Please do not create other array or use extra memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by iterating through the array once without using additional memory:

```
var decreasingOrder = true

for i in 0..<input.count - 1 {
    if (input[i] < input[i+1]) {
        decreasingOrder = false
    }
}
```